# Помогите с C++ | float и Char

Tags: c++

Есть переменная, которую получаю из класса (тип float):
`Class->floatVar`
Нужно вывести нормально с char

Попытался использовать sprintf, но он выводит первую букву

```
char str;
sprintf(&str, "say %e", (float)Class->floatVar); // допустим floatVar будет 132, str будет 1
```

Есть другие способы?

Comment: `char` это же только один символ, поэтому первый только у вас

Comment: Так у вас же str длиной в 1 символ. Сделайте массивом или указателем. Кроме того почему вы не хотите вывести float как %f?

Comment: Используйте `string` вместо `char`

Comment: либо, как вариант `char str[10]`

Comment: зачем тебе функции из Cи в C++?

Answer (score 4):

Вот так -

```
char str[40];
sprintf(str, "say %e", (float)Class->floatVar);
```

Т.е. должна быть выделена память для строки.

В С++ -

```
string str = to_string(Class->floatVar);
```